# Python Tkinter GUI: 'Clear result' button does not work

Tags: python, button, tkinter

This is my first python program. I'm trying to create torricelli's draintime calculator, but the 'clear result' button doesn't work. I want it to clear calculated results.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\David \Desktop  File\GUI_DrainTime_Calculator.py", line 83, in clear
    drain_label.destroy()
NameError: name 'drain_label' is not defined
```

Please help me figure why this NameError persists.
this is the culprit:

```
drain_label = Label(
    WIN, 
    font=('Helvetica', 8, 'bold'),
    text="The time it takes for the liquid to drain is: %.0f hour, %.0f minutes, and %.0f seconds." % (hr, Min, sec)).pack(side=BOTTOM)

def clear():
    drain_label.destroy()
    Clearbtn = Button(WIN, text="Clear Results", font('Helvetica',7,'bold'), fg='black',command=clear)
    Clearbtn.configure(background='grey')
    Clearbtn.pack(side=TOP,pady=5)
```

Thank you all !

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `textvariable` for your label. I also recommend using a Class for your program.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = tk.Frame(master)

        self.text_var = tk.StringVar()
        hr, min, sec = 1, 4, 20
        text = 'drain time = %.0f Hr, %0f Min, %.0f Sec' % (hr, min, sec)

        drain_label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=self.text_var).pack()

        clear_button = ttk.Button(frame, text='clear', command=self.destroy).pack()

        frame.pack()

    def destroy(self):
        self.text_var.set('')

root = tk.Tk()
app = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

you can use `tk.StringVar()` along with the `.get()` and `.set()` methods to get and set the string variable. you could also use string variables for `hr, min, sec` and pass those using a button.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `drain_label` is not `global`, hence the function can't see its definition/declaration anywhere, try passing `drain_label` as an argument in your function or make it `global`, though I advise avoid using global variables as much as possible.